# std::shared_ptr and initializer lists

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, shared-ptr, initializer-list

The std::shared_ptr constructor isn't behaving as I expected:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void func(std::vector<std::string> strings)
{
    for (auto const& string : strings)
    {
        std::cout << string << '\n';
    }
}

struct Func
{
    Func(std::vector<std::string> strings)
    {
        for (auto& string : strings)
        {
            std::cout << string << '\n';
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    func({"foo", "bar", "baz"});
    Func({"foo", "bar", "baz"});
    //auto ptr = std::make_shared<Func>({"foo", "bar", "baz"}); // won't compile.
    //auto ptr = std::make_shared<Func>{"foo", "bar", "baz"}; // nor this.
    return 0;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or is the compiler? The compiler is:

$ clang++ --version
Apple clang version 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-421.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)

edit: shared_ptr instead of make_shared.

Here's the error:

```
make -k 
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++    main.cc   -o main
main.cc:28:18: error: no matching function for call to 'make_shared'
      auto ptr = std::make_shared<Func>({"foo", "bar", "baz"});
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/memory:4621:1: note: candidate function not viable:
     requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
make_shared(_Args&& ...__args)
^
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try this:

```
auto ptr = std::make_shared<Func>(std::initializer_list<std::string>{"foo", "bar", "baz"});
```

Clang is not willing to deduce the type of `{"foo", "bar", "baz"}`.  I'm currently not sure whether that is the way the language is supposed to work, or if we're looking at a compiler bug.

Comment: Last I heard, it's known that perfect forwarding is not actually perfect at all when initializer lists are concerned.

Comment: {"foo",  "bar",  "baz"}  is not an expression and as such has no type (except when used with auto).. Although it would be nice

Comment: `{"foo", "bar", "baz"}` can be array of `std::string`, `char [][]`, `wchar_t [][]`.... Compiler must know exactly what it needs to create.

Answer (score 5):

The constructor of `shared_ptr<T>` takes a pointer of type `T*` as its argument, assumed to point to a dynamically allocated resource (or at least something that can be freed by the deleter). On the other hand, `make_shared` does the construction for you and takes the constructor arguments directly.

So either you say this:

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo> p(new Foo('a', true, Blue));
```

Or, much better and more efficiently:

```
auto p = std::make_shared<Foo>('a', true, Blue);
```

The latter form takes care of the allocation and construction for you, and in the process creates a more efficient implementation.

You could of course also say `make_shared<Foo>(Foo('a', true, Blue))`, but that would just create an unnecessary copy (which may be elided), and more importantly it creates needless redundancy. [*Edit*] For initializing your vector, this may be the best method:

```
auto p = std::make_shared<Func>(std::vector<std::string>({"a", "b", "c"}));
```

The important point is, though, that `make_shared` *performs the dynamic allocation* for you, while the shared-ptr constructor does *not*, and instead *takes ownership*.

Comment: "*but that would just create an unnecessary copy*" An unnecessary move.

Comment: @ildjarn: Well, that all depends, doesn't it? Anyway, "move" is just an optimized copy :-)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `make_shared` if you want to create a new object, constructed from those arguments, pointed to by a `shared_ptr`. `shared_ptr<T>` is like a pointer to `T`- it needs to be constructed with a *pointer* to `T`, not a `T`.

Edit: Perfect forwarding is in fact not at all perfect when initializer lists are involved (which is the suck). It's not a bug in the compiler. You will have to create an rvalue of type `Func` manually.

Comment: Sorry, the problem was with make_shared. I changed it to shared_ptr whilst futzing.