# Template function getting argument pack and initializer list

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, initializer-list

I have some templated classes like the ones below

```
template<typename T>
class A{
  public:
    A(T a0, T a1, T a2):a0_(a0),a1_(a1),a2_(a2){}
  private:
    T a0_,a1_,a2_;
};

template<typename T>
class B{
  public:
    B(T a, std::vector<T> b):a_(a),b_(b){}
  private:
    T a_;
    std::vector<T> b_;
};

template<typename T>
class C{
  public:
    C(T a, T b, std::vector<T> c):a_(a),b_(b),c_(c){}
  private:
    T a_,b_;
    std::vector<T> c_;
};
```

In general the classes constructor have an arbitrary number of arguments and optionally a `std::vector` in the end.

I wish to make a getter function that will allocate an instance of the above classes.

```
template< typename C, typename... Args>
C* get(Args... args){
  return new C(args...);
}
```

The getter function compiles successfully when the vector is explicitly created/defined.

```
A<int>* aa = get< A<int> >(1,2,3);

std::vector<int> v({1,2,3});
B<int>* bb = get< B<int> >(1,v);
C<int>* cc = get< C<int> >(1,2,v);

B<int>* bb = get< B<int> >(1,std::vector<int>({1,2,3}));
C<int>* cc = get< C<int> >(1,std::vector<int>({1,2,3}));
```

For usage simplicity, I would like to use initializer list to define the vector in `B` and `C`. This works fine when calling constructor directly.

```
A<int>* aa = new A<int>(1,2,3);
B<int>* bb = new B<int>(1,{1,2,3});
C<int>* cc = new C<int>(1,2,{1,2,3});
```

The getter function however gives a compile error

```
  B<int>* bb = get< B<int> >(1,{1,2,3});
  C<int>* cc = get< C<int> >(1,2,{1,2,3});
```

> error: too many arguments to function ‘C* get(Args ...) [with C = B; Args = {}]’

Creating a function specialization handling the vector like below was unsuccessful, too.

```
template< typename C, typename T, typename... Args>
C* get(Args... args, std::vector<T> v){
  return new C(args...,v);
}
```

Is it possible to create a getter function that will get the argument pack and the initializer list as last argument and create the object?

I use gcc 5.4 to compile.

Comment: Easy if you are willing to have the il be first.  Otherwise convoluted and/or impossible.

Comment: Thanks @Yakk, but in my real source the function are defined by me.

Comment: @ztuk I do not understand that response.

Comment: Sorry! I mean the constructors of the classes are defined by other developers in the project I work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is: `initializer_list` first.

If you accept that the `initializer_list` is the first argument of `get()`, you can write it as

```
template <template<typename> class C, typename T, typename... Args>
C<T>* get(std::initializer_list<T> il, Args ... args){
  return new C<T>(args..., il);
}
```

calling it as

```
   B<int>* bb = get<B, int>({1,2,3}, 1);
   C<int>* cc = get<C, int>({1,2,3}, 1, 2);
```

If you what the `initializer_list` in last position, there are problems in deduction of `Args...` pack of types.

Obviously you need another version of `get()` for not `vector` `C<T>` classes.

OT suggestion: you're using C++11, so you can (and I **strongly** suggest it) use smart pointers.

By example, using `unique_ptr`, your `get()` function could become

```
template <template<typename> class C, typename T, typename... Args>
std::unique_ptr<C<T>> get(std::initializer_list<T> il, Args ... args)
 { return std::unique_ptr<C<T>>(new C<T>(args..., il)); }
```

used as follows

```
std::unique_ptr<B<int>> bb { get<B, int >({1,2,3}, 1) };
std::unique_ptr<C<int>> cc { get<C, int >({1,2,3}, 1, 2) };
```

**--- EDIT ---**

The OP ask

> In any case, long story short, the answer to my question is: No, I
>   cannot have the initializer_list last. Right?

Never say "I cannot" but...

If you really, **really** want the `initializer_list` in last position... and if you can accept that the `Args...` argument are packed in a `std::tuple`...

```
template <std::size_t ...>
struct range
 { };

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Next>
struct rangeH 
 { using type = typename rangeH<N-1U, N-1U, Next ... >::type; };

template <std::size_t ... Next >
struct rangeH<0U, Next ... >
 { using type = range<Next ... >; };

template <template<typename> class C, typename T, typename ... Args,
          std::size_t ... I>
std::unique_ptr<C<T>> getH(std::tuple<Args...> const & t,
                           std::initializer_list<T> const & il,
                           range<I...> const)
 { return std::unique_ptr<C<T>>(new C<T>(std::get<I>(t)..., il)); }

template <template<typename> class C, typename T, typename... Args>
std::unique_ptr<C<T>> get(std::tuple<Args...> const & t,
                          std::initializer_list<T> const & il)
 { return getH<C, T>(t, il, typename rangeH<sizeof...(Args)>::type()); }
```

used as follows

```
std::unique_ptr<B<int>> bb { get<B, int >(std::make_tuple(1), {1,2,3}) };
std::unique_ptr<C<int>> cc { get<C, int >(std::make_tuple(1, 2), {1,2,3}) };
```

But... you really need the `initializer_list` is last position?

I think this last solution is horrible (compared with the preceding)

Comment: Thanks! I came across this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20059108/2707697 and thought of your solution. In any case, long story short, the answer to my question is: No, I cannot have the `initializer_list` last. Right?

Comment: @ztik - uhmmm... modified my answer trying to respond to yor last question

Comment: I agree with you that second solution does not seem preferable.

Answer (score 1):

It can't deduce `initializer_list` out of what you give it so the most simple way is to tell what it is explicitly. And to make it more concise you could use something like this:

```
template<typename T>
using IL = std::initializer_list<T>;
C<int>* cc2 = get< C<int> >(1, 2, IL<int>{1,2,3});
```